# Gesture Detector Precedence

Tags: flutter

I have a stack containing a `GestureDetector` (which is the up-most layer and spans across the whole screen) and another widget (under it) that eventually has a `ListView`. The problem is that the global `GestureDetector` uses `onHorizontalDrag` which consumes the touch event. Instead, I want the ListView to consume that event only.

In short, is there a way to make the `ListView` take precedence over the `GestureDetector` without keeping some sort of a state? Note, the `ListView` is not a child/sub-child of the `GestureDetector` - they are on different branches within the widget tree.

Answer (score 4):

I try out a stack with two GestureDetectors. It gives the highest preference to the GestureDetector which is placed last in the stack.

Example:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => {
            print("gesture detector1 event fired"),
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 600,
            width: 400,
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => {
            print("gesture detector2 event fired"),
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

When you click on the blue color container "Gesture Detector 2 is fired", you click on the red color container then "Gesture Detector 1 is fired"
[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMgoR.png)

Comment: Worked fine for my usecase. Saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

try adding `behavior: HitTestBehavoir.translucent` or `HitTestBehavoir.deferToChild` to the gestureture detector.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Again, the GestureDetector and ListView are in different widget branches, your suggestion will only work if they were parent/child